# Blogging Tool Needed for Standards Compliant Webpages

Tags: web-standards, blogs, platform

A programmer I know has a website that is fully Standards Compliant.  It uses Unicode-encoded fully-validated XHTML 1.1 with CSS. The pages are frames-free, table-free and JavaScript-free.

He would like to be directed to a blogging tool that does not demand any particular database system or web server, but does create static pages that comply with the above standards and best practices and is itself a professionally finished native Windows application.

...and it should be able to produce an RSS feed as well.

Is there anything out there that comes close to this?

Comment: Doesn't need to be free, but should be affordable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never heard of a standalone professional-quality Windows application that acts as a blog HTTP server.  I think your best bet is something like [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) with a good, standards-compliant theme (they exist) and some kind of blog-updating tool (I know they exist, and WordPress supports them, though I have only used [a Linux one](http://www.gnome.org/~seth/gnome-blog/)).

It may be worth investigating [MetaWeblog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaWeblog) for the Windows app portion, if you decide a single, stand-alone program doesn't exist that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you wouldn't want it to use a database, I can't think of any blogging engine that doesn't use one. It prevents you from having to change all your static files if you replace one thing in your template for example.

WordPress is probably the easiest to set up and integrates nicely with desktop Windows clients such as Windows Live Writer (http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/)